# Textbox omits the string after the double quote sign in Asp.net 3.5

Tags: asp.net

I am writing value to a textbox from handler(ashx) file. But the problem is that when the value contains double quote or single quote the textbox only shows the value before that quote and omits the the string after that quote.
For eg Value is: Hi "there
The textbox shows: Hi 
Please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

Use a escape sequence '\' before using ". So, like this -

```
Textbox.Text = "Hi \"there";
```